# Configuring a React App to Work with Preexisting CodeIgniter code

Tags: web-development, php, react

I am quite new to this, but I am currently redesigning an older webpage that uses a CodeIgniter backend to be built with a new React.js front-end application. The React.js app is *fully built using the App.js structure*. I am trying to minimize the changes to the backend since it is already quite good and fleshed out (stored evidently in the *controllers* section of the CodeIgniter application), so this necessitates that I have to update the *views* section of the CodeIgniter application rather than do the smarter thing of creating a REST API. Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: I think this is off-topic since you are not actually looking for software.  Rather you want to know how to us eit.